# Property value is not valid: Keyword not support: 'host'?

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to import some Oracle tables. I selected ".Net Framework Data Provider for Oracle" since I don't have the Ole DB driver.

The following is the Oracle connection string

```
Host=xxx.yyy.net;Port=1523;Service Name=aaaaa.bbb;User Id=userid;Password=abcded
```

However, it popped up an error message after filled the `ConnectionString`.

> Property value is not valid.
>
> Keyword not supported: 'host'

---

I changed the connection string to `Data Source=myDs;User Id=userid;Password=abcded`, and then clicked the "Next" button. The following error popped up.

```
The operation could not be completed.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
 (System.Data.OracleClient)
```

I created a file `network\admin\tnsnames.ora` with the data source name `myDs` under the oracle home.

Comment: I'm guessing that you will still need some form of Oracle driver installed. Since the code says that the keyword `host` is not supported, what makes you think it should be? From where did you get this form of connection string?

Comment: I've updated the question. I changed the connection string

Comment: It's been a long time since I dealt with Oracle clients, but I seem to remember that you had to run some local oracle configuration tool to set up a local TNS name to point to your remote instance, and then you could reference this name in your connection strings. If this sounds right, did you do this? (I might be completely wrong, or this may have changed entirely since back then)

Comment: How does your entry for `myDs` look like?

Comment: `myDs = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = .....`. I just modified the sample file.

Answer (score 0):

You can usually put the long description string into your connection string. Instead of

```
Data Source=myDs;User Id=userid;Password=abcded
```

try something like this:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = .....));User Id=userid;Password=abcded
```

If you don't want to try that or it doesn't work, that "cannot resolve connect identifier" message usually means the client isn't finding your TNSNames file - may need to set the environment variable TNS_ADMIN or find whatever other configuration problem you have going on.